# Unable to getCurrentUser for AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, referenceerror

Newbie to JS and getting the below error with AWS Cognito. I am not able to work out why it is not able to recognize AmazonCognitoIdentity even i have mentioned it explicitly in import statement...

ReferenceError: AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js" ></script>
import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

userAuth();

function userAuth() {

    var data = {
        UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_*****',
        ClientId: '********'
    };

    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser != null) {
console.log("Success");
}
else {
console.log("Failure");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: try `var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require("amazon-cognito-identity-js");` instead of the import. Curious if it makes a difference.

Comment: also, why not use `aws-sdk` insteak of `amazon-cognito-identity-js`... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried changing 'code` import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'; to 
    var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require("amazon-cognito-identity-js")  but it didnt make any difference. I also tried using aws-sdk earlier but it does not have any method CognitoUserPool() and I was getting a different error unfortunately. As per my understanding, to get AmazonCognitoIdentity, we need to use amazon-cognito-identity-js which has CognitoPool method which we can use to call get userPool an subsequently getCurrrentUser.

Comment: Okay, I was able to work this out after some struggle. I was using amazon-cognito-identity-js because I was trying to use var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(data); And CognitoUserPool was not available in AWS-SDK. CognitoUserPool is required to get the userpool which can be used to get the current user and subsequently user session and finally user token! But I got the token directly from the browser itself directly, so dont need to use CognitoUserPool. Hence all the subsequent problems were solved!!